# How do I pass to other gulp tasks from gulp watch

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I'm pretty new to gulp, here's what's happening

I did have:

```
gulp.watch(config.build.sass + '/**/*.scss', ['sass-dev']);
```

But this didn't catch any new files, so after reading the docs I need to have:

```
gulp.watch({
    glob: config.build.sass + '/**/*.scss',
    emit: 'all'
}, ['sass-dev']);
```

But this throws an error: `Object #<Object> has no method 'indexOf'` as the last part is incorrect.

Can anyone tell me the syntax I need to run my `sass-dev` task on anything emitted from watch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
gulp.watch(config.build.sass + '/**/*.scss', {emit: 'all'}, ['sass-dev']);
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem there is that it doesn't pick up on any new files in the directory. The docs state that I need to use glob to watch the directory for new files, and existing. It then doesn't explain how to pass on to existing gulp tasks.

Comment: Which docs are you looking at? I don't see any mention of a `glob` option in the [gulp api docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob--opts-tasks-or-gulpwatchglob--opts-cb). Only a `glob` argument.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-watch   Is this not the right gulp watch docset?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example seems fine. No need to use glob option. But it depends on what `config.build.sass` is.

```
gulp.watch(config.build.sass + '/**/*.scss', ['sass-dev']);
```

If you'd like to use `glob` option, try this.

```
gulp.watch(config.build.sass + '/**/*.scss', { some_option: value }, ['sass-dev']);
```

Comment: It's just a path string. So it seems I'm looking at the wrong documentation then.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. See API docs. https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpwatchglob-opts-cb

Comment: To be fair, I have to accept Ben's answer as he said it first. But you were right too.